# MySQL - Supertype/Subtype design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to create the following database:

[image]

For semi-trucks I don't need extra subtypes, while for Car I need to have only those 3 subtypes and also for Sedan I need the four subtypes.
For SELECTs I will use JOINs (normalized database) but I need to find an easy way to make INSERTs.

- Vehicle table stores common information
- Semi-truck stores specific information for semis
- Car tables has specific fields for cars and a car_type field which is linked to the three subtypes
- Van, Suv and Sedan (and other types if I would need them) should be in one table CAR_TYPE
- However, for Sedan type I need to have additional subtypes which maybe should be contained in another table. These subtypes are not needed for Suvs and Vans (in real life suv, vans can have the same subtypes as sedans but not in my case).

I need this database to be created exactly as it is in the diagram.

So far, my first approach is to have the following tables:

- Vehicle: veh_id, veh_type(Semi, car), ..., other_fields
- Vehicle_semis: veh_id, ..., other_semis_fields
- Vehicle_car: veh_id, car_type(Van, Suv, Sedan), other_car_specific_fields
- Car_type: car_type_id, type
- Sedan_type: sedan_type_id, type

My problem is that I'm not sure this would be the right approach, and I don't know exactly how to create relationships between the tables.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

The following diagram is based on @Mike 's answer:
[image]

Comment: first step is to determine what would the primary (most used) operation for this db : read , write (insert,update,delete) because the design will be very different for each case, also what amount of data will you have , will it grow in the future ? if so how much ? how many clients will interrogate the db? how often ? these are just a few questions that you need to aware of

Comment: @Stephan - Data will grow in future, 100k maybe. My primary operation would be READ. As for clients, there would be a quite a lot of them working with the db!

Comment: in the schema you purposed the may problem is at read since the data is "very" normalized ... imagine if you have to retrieve some sedans for ex you would need 4 joins or more which is not very efficient but given the low data volume it shouldn't be a problem even for many users . I recommend to use InnoDB engine because it has 2 key features for ur app : transactional support and row level locking

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks for the advice on what engine to use. You say that the data would be too normalized. Is there any other way you would design it? I suppose that the three tables Vehicle, Vehicle_Semis and Vehicle_Car you would not change since they have common fields and separate as well (or would you). But what about the other ones?

Comment: for large volumes of data were the read part is intense its a common practice to have a normalized mode but also a denormalized one ... in your case it could be a single table to hold all the data so that you do not need a single join

Comment: @Stephan - Well, I would do that but I'm still stuck on how to deal with the subtypes. I want to have the subtypes somehow in different tables so that I can extract them from the database and display them on the website. I wanna use an id and a type (1, Van; 2, Suv; 3, Sedan). I'll need this in case I would need to add other subtypes as the data grows. Same thing for the Sedan subtypes.

Comment: as i've said you design is ok for a normalized model and yes you need a type field as you said. but for now i do not think the denormalized model is required ... you can add it over time if you have read performances

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before I get started, I want to point out that "gas" describes either fuel or a kind of engine, not a kind of sedan. Think hard before you keep going down this path. (Semantics are more important in database design than most people think.)

What you want to do is fairly simple, but not necessarily easy. The important point in this kind of supertype/subtype design (also known as an exclusive arc) is to make it impossible to have rows about sedans referencing rows about semi-trucks, etc..

MySQL makes the code more verbose, because it doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. You're lucky; in your application, the CHECK constraints can be replaced by additional tables and foreign key constraints.  Comments refer to the SQL *above* them.

```
create table vehicle_types (
  veh_type_code char(1) not null,
  veh_type_name varchar(10) not null,
  primary key (veh_type_code),
  unique (veh_type_name)
);

insert into vehicle_types values
('s', 'Semi-truck'), ('c', 'Car');
```

This is the kind of thing I might implement as a CHECK constraint on other platforms. You can do that when the meaning of the codes is obvious to users. I'd expect users to know or to figure out that 's' is for semis and 'c' is for cars, or that views/application code would hide the codes from users.

```
create table vehicles (
  veh_id integer not null,
  veh_type_code char(1) not null,
  other_columns char(1) default 'x',
  primary key (veh_id),
  unique (veh_id, veh_type_code),
  foreign key (veh_type_code) references vehicle_types (veh_type_code)
);
```

The UNIQUE constraint lets the pair of columns {veh_id, veh_type_code} be the target of a foreign key reference. That means a "car" row can't possibly reference a "semi" row, even by mistake.

```
insert into vehicles (veh_id, veh_type_code) values
(1, 's'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'c'), 
(6, 'c'), (7, 'c');

create table car_types (
  car_type char(3) not null,
  primary key (car_type)
);

insert into car_types values
('Van'), ('SUV'), ('Sed');

create table veh_type_is_car (
  veh_type_car char(1) not null,
  primary key (veh_type_car)
);
```

Something else I'd implement as a CHECK constraint on other platforms.  (See below.)

```
insert into veh_type_is_car values ('c');
```

Only one row ever.

```
create table cars (
  veh_id integer not null,
  veh_type_code char(1) not null default 'c',
  car_type char(3) not null,
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x',
  primary key (veh_id ),
  unique (veh_id, veh_type_code, car_type),
  foreign key (veh_id, veh_type_code) references vehicles (veh_id, veh_type_code),
  foreign key (car_type) references car_types (car_type),
  foreign key (veh_type_code) references veh_type_is_car (veh_type_car)
);
```

The default value for veh_type_code, along with the foreign key reference to veh_type_is_car, guarantees that this rows in this table can be only about cars, and can *only* reference vehicles that are cars. On other platforms, I'd just declare the column veh_type_code as `veh_type_code char(1) not null default 'c' check (veh_type_code = 'c')`.

```
insert into cars (veh_id, veh_type_code, car_type) values
(2, 'c', 'Van'), (3, 'c', 'SUV'), (4, 'c', 'Sed'),
(5, 'c', 'Sed'), (6, 'c', 'Sed'), (7, 'c', 'Sed');

create table sedan_types (
  sedan_type_code char(1) not null,
  primary key (sedan_type_code)
);

insert into sedan_types values
('g'), ('d'), ('h'), ('e');

create table sedans (
  veh_id integer not null,
  veh_type_code char(1) not null,
  car_type char(3) not null,
  sedan_type char(1) not null,
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x',
  primary key (veh_id),
  foreign key (sedan_type) references sedan_types (sedan_type_code),
  foreign key (veh_id, veh_type_code, car_type) references cars (veh_id, veh_type_code, car_type)
);

insert into sedans (veh_id, veh_type_code, car_type, sedan_type) values 
(4, 'c', 'Sed', 'g'), (5, 'c', 'Sed', 'd'), (6, 'c', 'Sed', 'h'),
(7, 'c', 'Sed', 'e');
```

If you have to build additional tables that reference sedans, such as gas_sedans, diesel_sedans, etc., then you need to build one-row tables similar to "veh_type_is_car" and set foreign key references to them.

In production, I'd revoke permissions on the base tables, and either use

- updatable views to do the inserts and updates, or
- stored procedures to do the inserts and updates.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It is exactly what I needed! One thing I don't fully understand is "veh_type_is_car" which would have the same code "c" as the "veh_type_code" from "cars" table. Is that just to help in better coding or queries? The relationship between vehicles and cars includes the code "c" as well. Why would I add that table?

Comment: @Cristian: There's a foreign key in "cars" that references that table. It guarantees that *only* 'c' can appear in that column if the row is about a car. That is, it prevents a semi-truck row in "vehicles" from being linked to a car row in "cars".

Comment: Ok, got it. I suppose the role of guaranteeing that only "c" make it to "cars" table can also be implemented by code too. Would it be too much to have it in both mysql and code? Overkill?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "implemented by code". If you can use the MySQL command-line interface to do something besides what those declarative constraints guarantee, then no, they can't be implemented by code.  (The behavior and guarantees provided by the dbms are different from the behavior and guarantees provided by application code.) But it's not unusual to have application code check for sane values and provide helpful, friendly recommendations for fixing them before sending those values to the dbms.

Comment: "implemented by code" = application code. Thanks so much. I will do a lot of checking too in the application code and also use your suggestions for the db checks!

Answer (score 4):

I refer you to the "Info" tab under the following three tags:

[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

The first two describe the two major design patterns for dealing with a class/subclass (aka type/subtype) situation when designing a relational database.  The third descibes a technique for using a single primary key that gets assigned in the superclass table and gets propagated to the subclass tables.

They don't completely answer the questions you raise, but they shed some light on the whole topic.  This topic, of mimicking inheritance in SQL,  comes up over and over again in both SO and the DBA area.