# Maintaining integrity while adding foreign keys to subtypes in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I've run into a particular issue with a MySQL database as the system gets more complex.

The functionality we need requires we have a database with `forms`.

`forms` have multiple subtypes: `bin-forms` and `truck-forms`.

Each type of `form` can have many `custom_fields`.

In the future, there will probably be other tables which can have `custom_fields` as well.

And of course, `custom_fields` has many `custom_field_values`.

So here's a crude depiction of my idea.

```
forms
----
id
type_id //fk to types id 

bin_forms
----
id
form_id //fk to forms id
type_id //fk to forms type_id (check = 1)

truck_forms
----
id
form_id //fk to forms id
type_id //fk to forms type_id (check = 2)

types
----
id

custom_fields
----
id
type_id //fk to types id

custom_field_values
----
id
custom_field_id //fk to custom_fields id
form_id //fk to forms id
```

So my question is about best practices.

Is it fine to add a check constraint to a foreign
key since the `types` table will pretty much be static anyway?

Is it good practice to have a `types` table when the subtypes are already explicit by virtue of them being sub-typed tables?

And how can I prepare for the future in terms of allowing another table, say `widgets`, to 
use `custom_fields`? Maybe change `forms` to `typed_forms`, have that be a subtype of 
`forms`, then `widgets has many forms`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Supertype/Subtype design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405702/mysql-supertype-subtype-design)

Comment: That is some intense design. Answers my question wonderfully, thank you. Will upvote it once I have the reputation to do so.