# How to handle super/sub types in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have been given assignment of big database design for e-commerce. In that database design, I'm confused at 3 entities. 1st entity is "employee", 2nd is "fulltime" and third is "casual". Employee is super and rest of the two entities are sub type entities. Now the problem is:

I was advised if admin inserts employee record in "employee" table and in fulltime then the same user can't add in casual table or vice versa. It should be handled by database not by programming language because it is pure database assignment. I have attached an image. I hope it will help you understand my point. So if it is possible then please explain how to restrict user/system to enter data only in one table for same employee (full time/ casual)  [image]

Comment: In the real world, an employee that's "casual" today might be "fulltime" tomorrow. Your question suggests that, when that happens, you'll delete a row from "casual" and insert a row in "fulltime". And that raises questions about the value for "employee"."emp_startdate".

Comment: See [the answer to this similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17407959/562459) with vehicles.