# MySQL database with user/admin rights

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I need to create an API server using Node.js and MySQL that supports 2 types of users: admin, user
Admin should have rights to all CRUD operations and as well as creating another admin accounts.
But I am not sure how to differentiate admin and user while creating a model in MySQL.
Thanks!

Comment: how about roles?? or add a flag at least to a user.. something like "flag_admin = 0 or 1" ..  then in your NodeJS always check if the user has this flag before performing ADMIN-restricted operations ...  it's a simple middleware (add it to all your "admin" requests to make sure only admin can do this - ideally within the JWT token)

Comment: If you will just have the two types of users you could add an `isAdmin` column on the users table. Or have the user table linked to a user_roles table. Then in node create some middleware to protect certain routes dependent on the type of user

Comment: Pls read the following answer to the duplicate question to get an overview of the possible data modelling options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408392/5389997